Suprema BioMini with C# - where should UFLicense.dat be put?
I'm developing a C# application using the BioMini SDK for fingerprint scanning. When running my application, I encountered the following error:
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in BioMini.UFScanner.dll
I have ensured that BioMini.UFScanner.dll is correctly referenced in my project and is located in the bin\Debug folder. However, I still encounter this issue. How can I resolve the System.DllNotFoundException error when using the BioMini SDK in my C# application?
COM Error with ufscanner.dll: Despite uploading ufscanner.dll, I'm now encountering a COM error.
I've tried registering ufscanner.dll using regsvr32, checked dependencies with Dependency Walker, and ensured correct placement of the DLL. However, the issue persists. How can I resolve this COM error when using the BioMini SDK in my C# application?
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BioMini;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq.Expressions;


namespace Fingerprint1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private UFScannerManager scannerManager;
        private UFScanner scanner;
        public Form1()
        {
            
            InitializeBioMiniSDK();
        }

        private void InitializeBioMiniSDK()
        {
            try
            {
                scannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);
                UFS_STATUS ufs_res = scannerManager.Init();
                if (ufs_res == UFS_STATUS.OK)
                    if (scannerManager.Scanners.Count > 0)
                    {
                        scanner = scannerManager.Scanners[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No scanners found.");
                    }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize scanner manager. Error code: " + ufs_res);
                }
            }
            catch (DllNotFoundException dllEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"DLL not found: {dllEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occured: {ex.Message}");
            }
                
        }
        private void captureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (scanner != null)
            {
                UFS_STATUS resultCode;
                int width = 0, height = 0, resolution = 0;

                // get capture image buffer info
                resultCode = scanner.CaptureSingleImage();
                if (resultCode == UFS_STATUS.OK)
  
                    {
                    //allocate buffer for the image data
                    byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[Width * Height];

                    // capture image into buffer
                    resultCode = scanner.GetCaptureImageBufferInfo(out width,  out height,out resolution);
                    if (resultCode == UFS_STATUS.OK)
                    {
                        // Create bitmap from the captured image buffer
                        Bitmap fingerprintBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                        // Lock the bitmap's bits
                        var bmpData = fingerprintBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,fingerprintBitmap.Width, fingerprintBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, fingerprintBitmap.PixelFormat);
                      

                        // Copy the image data into the bitmap
                        Marshal.Copy(imageBuffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, imageBuffer.Length);

                        // Unlock the bits
                        fingerprintBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

                        // Set grayscale palette
                        var palette = fingerprintBitmap.Palette;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                        {
                            palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
                        }

                        // Display the bitmap in the pictureBox
                        fingerprintPictureBox.Image = fingerprintBitmap;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to capture image.");
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to get capture image buffer info.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Scanner not initialized.");
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void fingerprintPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
